# How can I reproduce some surface plots in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d

[image]

I am not really familiar with *Mathematica*. I wonder if some one can help me draw any of the following surfaces. I will be appreciative if you tell me how to use equations and `PlotRange` to draw those.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Where do these images come from?  Do you want to draw these three specific shapes or are they merely examples?

Comment: A good starting point will be [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) and [that](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html).

Comment: I wanted to draw those and I kind of got the first two but about the last one I am not sure .

Comment: First one: RegionPlot3D[
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= z && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 120, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.5]]]

Comment: Second one: Show[Graphics3D[{Yellow, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Red, 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 2}, 1], Blue, Sphere[{0, 0, -2}, 1]}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}] , 
 ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 120, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.3]]]]

Answer (score 9):

```
GraphicsRow[
     {ParametricPlot3D[{{t Sin@p, t Cos@p, t},
                       {{0, 0, 1 - Cos@1} + {t Sin@p, t Cos@p, Cos@t}}}, 
                       {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2}}],
      ParametricPlot3D[{{  Sin@p Sqrt[1 - TriangleWave[t]^2],
                           Cos@p Sqrt[1 - TriangleWave[t]^2],
                         Pi t}, 
                         {Cos[p/2], Sin[p/2], Pi t}},
                         {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2}], 
      ParametricPlot3D[{Sin@p TriangleWave@t, Cos@p TriangleWave@t, 3 t},
                       {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}]}]
```

[image]